# Python : Read all files in directory to watch inside while loop

Tags: python

I am working on a python script, where I will be passing a directory, and I need to get all log-files from it. Currently, I have a small script which watches for any changes to these files and then processes that information.

It's working good, but it's just for a single file, and hardcoded file value. How can I pass a directory to it, and still watch all the files. My confusion is since I am working on these files in a while loop which should always stay running, how can I do that for n number of files inside a directory?

Current code :

```
import time

f = open('/var/log/nginx/access.log', 'r')
while True:
    line = ''
    while len(line) == 0 or line[-1] != '\n':
        tail = f.readline()
        if tail == '':
            time.sleep(0.1)          # avoid busy waiting
            continue
        line += tail
        print(line)
        _process_line(line)
```

Question was already tagged for duplicate, but the requirement is to get changes line by line from all files inside directory. Other questions cover single file, which is already working.

Comment: Have you considered using [inotify](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) which is designed for just this usecase?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Monitoring contents of files/directories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597903/monitoring-contents-of-files-directories)

Comment: @SiHa No, any answer on that page are specifically for single files. How do I utilize inotify to get changes line by line as I mentioned in the code?

Comment: Doing it line-by-line for a directory full of files is an incredibly inefficient way to do it, and there are already mechanisms available to do this for you without having to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: @SiHa : I need the changes in file. See this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25350252/any-ways-to-show-file-changes-with-pyinotify-for-example

Inotify doesn't give the changes in file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this library: watchdog.

> Python API library and shell utilities to monitor file system events.

https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/

Simple [example](https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/quickstart.html#a-simple-example):

```py
import sys
import time
import logging
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import LoggingEventHandler

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                        format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s',
                        datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    path = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else '.'
    event_handler = LoggingEventHandler()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=True)
    observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

Comment: I think the path u mentioned is the directory which I should pass. Where do I get the changes happening inside the file?

Comment: https://medium.com/@xiaoouwang/create-a-watchdog-in-python-to-look-for-filesystem-changes-aaabefd14de4

Comment: This doesn't give the actual changes done... Whether the file was modified or not is not relavant, only the new changes. :-)

Comment: you can save the last line you read, and on the event - read from there

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure if I understand what your trying to do, but maybe use:

```
while True: 
    files = os.listdir(directory) 
    for file in files:
 
    --You're code for checking contents of the file--
```

Comment: Won't work, since I am tailing a file constantly....